# ¿Cómo valido una Promise.all()?

Tags: javascript, promesas, error404, async-await

Estoy haciendo una webapp, en la que ingresando un artista y el nombre de una canción suya, te devuelve la letra de dicha canción + información de dicho artista. Funciona todo bien, el problema es que **cuando la canción ingresada o el artista no coincide**, no sé como avisarle al usuario. Es decir, no sé cómo *validar* la Promise.

**Cuando esto ocurre, en consola recibo**: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

**Mientras tanto, el código que utilizo para esta operacion es**: `const [ letraAPI, infoAPI] = await Promise.all([ Axios(url), Axios(url2) ])`

Hace poco empecé en la programación, disculpas si tengo algún error tonto. Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias!

Answer (score 6):

Las promesas pueden ser resueltas o pueden ser rechazadas. Si trabajamos con una única promesa, tenemos los métodos `.then` y `.catch`:

```js
function crearPromesa(resultado, resolveOrReject) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolveOrReject? resolve(resultado): reject('error');
  })
}

let prueba= crearPromesa('Hola', true);
prueba.then(resultado=> {
  console.log('resuelto con', resultado);
}).catch(error => {
  console.log('falló con', error);
});

prueba= crearPromesa('Hola', false);
prueba.then(resultado=> {
  console.log('resuelto con', resultado);
}).catch(error => {
  console.log('falló con', error);
});
```

¿Pero qué pasa cuando trabajamos con varias promesas? Entonces tenemos el método `.all` para agruparlas:

```js
function crearPromesa(resultado, resolveOrReject, millis) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolveOrReject? resolve(resultado): reject('error con '+resultado);
    }, millis);
  });
}

Promise.all([
  crearPromesa(1,true,100),
  crearPromesa(2,true,200)
]).then(resultado => {
  console.log(resultado.toString());
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});

Promise.all([
  crearPromesa(1,true,100),
  crearPromesa(2,false,250),
  crearPromesa(3,true,300)
]).then(resultado => {
  console.log(resultado.toString());
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Este método se comporta de la siguiente manera: si todas las promesas se resuelven, en el método `then` se recibe un array con los resultados en el mismo orden en el que se introdujeron, **no en el orden en el que se completaron**.

Pero si falla una sola, entonces **nunca** se ejecutará `then` y en `catch` sólo recibiremos la que falló.

En la última revisión del estándar (ES2020) se ha añadido un nuevo método: `allSettled`. Es similar a `.all`, pero la diferencia es que si una promesa de la lista falla, no impide obtener el resto de resultados: Para cada promesa obtendremos su estado y su resultado:

```js
function crearPromesa(resultado, resolveOrReject, millis) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolveOrReject? resolve(resultado): reject('error con '+resultado);
    }, millis);
  });
}

Promise.allSettled([
  crearPromesa(1,true,100),
  crearPromesa(2,false,200),
  crearPromesa(4,true,300)
]).then(resultados => {
  resultados.forEach(resultado => console.log(resultado));
});
```

Pero si trabajamos con `async/await`, hemos de usar bloques `try/catch` para tratar los errores. Pero, como `Promise.allSettled` nunca "falla", no necesitas capturar los errores en ese caso:

```js
function crearPromesa(resultado, resolveOrReject, millis) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolveOrReject? resolve(resultado): reject('error con '+resultado);
    }, millis);
  });
}

async function conAll() {
  try {
    let resultados = await Promise.all([
      crearPromesa(1,true,100),
      crearPromesa(2,false,200),
      crearPromesa(4,true,300)
    ]);
  } catch(error) {
    console.log('error:',error);
  }
}

async function conAllSettled() {
 
    let resultados = await Promise.allSettled([
      crearPromesa(1,true,100),
      crearPromesa(2,false,200),
      crearPromesa(4,true,300)
    ]);
    //no se lanza un error
    resultados.forEach(resultado => console.log(resultado));
 
}

conAll();
conAllSettled();
```